# Making a JSON callback (same page) creating a table from a list

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary

In my .py file I have a dictionary with keys and values as follow

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for i in results:
   for key,value in i.items():
     result[key].append(value)
return jsonify(result=str(result))
```

and in my html file I am trying to create a table as follows

```
$(function() {
  $('a#search').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/_search', {
      a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      var tableData = '<table>'
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        tableData += '<tr>';
        alert(key)
        tableData += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
        tableData += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
        tableData += '</tr>';
      });
      tableData += '</table>';
      $('#table').html(tableData);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

What might I be doing wrong? because a table is created but with result (which I dont know why it is being save into a td when its not in the dict) and everything else is in another td? Any help to extract the keys and values from the dict would be appreciated

```
<td>result</td> 
 <td>defaultdict(, {'Developer': ['Office Koukan', 'Jorudan', 'Beam Software'], 'Publisher': ['Shouei', 'VAP', 'Hi Tech Expressions'], 'ReleaseDate': ['March 18, 1994', 'November 18, 1994', 'October 1, 1993'], 'Title': ['Idea no Hi', 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou', 'hunThe Hunt for Red October']})</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are returning `jsonify(result=str(result))`. Try doing just `jsonify(result=result)`.

Comment: Tried that but instead I get in my table result [object Object]

Comment: Nvm I added to data in the JSON call data.result and it worked thanks

Comment: Ah yes, you would get the output as per your variable definition (`result=`).

Comment: Thanks again real quick question is there a way to separate the values of the dictionary into its own td instead of printing all values for keys at once?

Comment: Just add another `for` loop inside the existing one. `$.each(value, function(val){`...

Comment: hmm doesnt seem to work but thanks anyway ill keep trying